# AWS EC2 group randomly scaled up then back down, why might this have happened?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase

I had an AWS EC2 instance, just finished installing HBase (Hadoop database) on it this morning. Around that time, it suddenly started scaling via auto scaling I had set up earlier. An hour or so later, it scaled back down. But I wasn't doing anything and I haven't distributed this server's information to anyone. Doesn't this seem suspicious? Am I missing something?

Comment: May be that was due to the HBase running its pre-computations or any high cpu/memory intensive task that triggered the auto-scaling. 

You can check the EC2 matrices to confirm the sudden spike in load.

Comment: What is the Scaling Policy that you have associated with the Auto Scaling group?